# How to update all records in a table with values from another table where records match by id?

Tags: sql, oracle, batch-updates

Suppose I have two tables:

```
USER
+------+------+-------------------+
|   ID | NAME | CREATED_TIMESTAMP |
+------+------+-------------------+
|    1 |   N1 |              Null |
+------+------+-------------------+
|    2 |   N2 |              Null | <--------- acceptor of reference-value
+------+------+-------------------+           \
|  ... |  ... |               ... |            \
+------+------+-------------------+             \
                                                 \ 
REFERENCE_CREATED_TIMESTAMPS                      \
+-------------+----+-------------------+            these records match
|  TABLE_NAME | ID |CREATED_TIMESTAMP  |          /
+-------------+----+-------------------+         /
|        USER |  1 | 12.03.12 17:20:40 |        /
+-------------+----+-------------------+       /
|        USER |  2 | 14.03.12 10:12:54 |  <--- reference-value
+-------------+----+-------------------+
|   FOO_TABLE |  1 | 17.05.12 08:10:01 |
+-------------+----+-------------------+
|         ... | ...|               ... |
+-------------+----+-------------------+
```

Now I want to fill CREATE_TIMESTAMP column in USER table taking the values from `REFERENCE_CREATED_TIMESTAMPS` table, i.e. for the user with ID=2 I will use a value of `CREATED_TIMESTAMP` from `REFERENCE_CREATED_TIMESTAMPS` row where `TABLE_NAME=USER` and `ID=2`.

What will be the query to do this for all records of the USER table?

Comment: Lots of good example update queries at [psoug.org](http://psoug.org/reference/update.html), but I think @Amit has it right for your specific case.

Answer (score 4):

try like this..

```
Update UserTable Set CREATED_TIMESTAMP=
(Select Min(CREATED_TIMESTAMP) from REFERENCE_CREATED_TIMESTAMPS where
 REFERENCE_CREATED_TIMESTAMPS.Id=UserTable.Id and Table_Name='User')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
update  "User"
set     CREATED_TIMESTAMP =
        (
        select  rct.CREATED_TIMESTAMP
        from    REFERENCE_CREATED_TIMESTAMPS rct
        where   rct.ID = "User".ID
                and rct.TABLE_NAME = 'USER'
        );
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/336e0/3/0)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
  update USER u, REFERENCE_CREATED_TIMESTAMPS r
  set u.CREATED_TIMESTAMP = b.CREATED_TIMESTAMP
  where u.ID = r.ID AND r.TABLE_NAME = 'USER'
        AND u.ID = 2;
```

Comment: While that will work in MySQL, multi-table updates are not standard SQL and I do not think that will work with Oracle.